# Replace a text of a span element inside an a tag using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

How can I replace the word "Pipelines" to "NewText" in the following HTML code using JavaScript?

```
<a href="/v2/location/wrbZF5pqYXJwNagoqTEO/settings/pipeline" class="w-full group px-3 flex items-center justify-start sm:justify-center md:justify-center lg:justify-start xl:justify-start text-sm font-medium rounded-md cursor-pointer font-medium opacity-70 hover:opacity-100 py-2 md:py-2" id="sb_pipeline" exact-path-active-class="exact-path-active-class" meta="pipeline">
<!---->
<span class="hl_text-overflow hidden md:hidden nav-title lg:block xl:block hl_force-block"> Pipelines </span>
<!----><!----><!----></a>
```

I've tried using the following code to change the text content of the span element inside the a tag, but it didn't work `document.getElementById("sb_pipeline").getElementsByTagName("span")[0].textContent = "New Text";`

Comment: Possible you have a bad condition that's preventing your code to be executed. Works just fine on jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/fucsz8qj/

Comment: @MarioVernari Not true. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following script

```
    <a
  href="/v2/location/wrbZF5pqYXJwNagoqTEO/settings/pipeline"
  class="w-full group px-3 flex items-center justify-start sm:justify-center md:justify-center lg:justify-start xl:justify-start text-sm font-medium rounded-md cursor-pointer font-medium opacity-70 hover:opacity-100 py-2 md:py-2"
  id="sb_pipeline"
  exact-path-active-class="exact-path-active-class"
  meta="pipeline"
>
  <!---->
  <span
    class="hl_text-overflow hidden md:hidden nav-title lg:block xl:block hl_force-block"
  >
    Pipelines
  </span>
  <!----><!----><!----></a
>

<script>
   document.querySelector("#sb_pipeline .nav-title").innerText = "New Text";
</script>
```